# C++ vector randomised the same way after each random shuffle

Tags: c++, random, vector, shuffle

I've tried a number of ways to randomise the items in a vector container in C++.  Though more than that the items have to be different each time they are randomised.  At the moment it is spitting out the same randomly shuffled vector each time.

The methods I've used are as follows:

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////
METHOD 1
srand(time(0));
random_shuffle(mapkeys.begin(), mapkeys.end());

METHOD 2
int myrandom (int i) { return std::rand()%i;}
random_shuffle(mapkeys.begin(), mapkeys.end(), myrandom);

METHOD 3
auto engine = default_random_engine{};
shuffle(begin(mapkeys), end(mapkeys), engine);

METHOD 4
default_random_engine gen(unsigned(time (NULL)));
shuffle(begin(mapkeys), end(mapkeys), gen);
/////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

I found these from various questions here on stack. While I understand the concept of needing to pass the seed into random_shuffle, it does not seem to work for me.  If someone could not only point out but explain to me the error that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you pass the seed in you'll get the same sequence each time (that's what the seed is published for).  If you want to randomise it you have to randomise the seed first, assuming it starts with some default value.

Comment: but if I base that on the time as in method 1, shouldn't that be random 'enough'?

Comment: Yes - sorry I missed that.

Comment: You are aware of the fact that you should only seed once? And that seeding with `time(NULL)` multiple times a second will end up generating the same sequence again? Also, you should not use `rand` and `random_shuffle` anymore, use the `<random>` facilities and `std::shuffle` instead. See also [this](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful).

Comment: Notwithstanding Baum's comment, I tried method (1) and it worked for me.

Comment: yeah think thats cos rand for me is being called repeatedly, cheers for that!